# Python: How do I parallelize a job that compares two lists?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

I have two lists and need to compare and calculate element by element. As these lists get larger, performance is suffering.  Someone recommended breaking one of the lists into N sections and running the comparison in parallel. How do I run these in parallel?

```
key={}
#compare each list, element by element
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        matched = False
        try:
            matched = match_function(list[i]['typeforma'], list[i]['typeformb'],list[j]['typeforma'], list[j]['typeformb'], ) 
        except:
            print("Error",i,j)
        if matched:
            # store two matches in the dictionary
            key[list2[j]['id']]=list1[i]['identifier']
            break;
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Comment: Provide more information about the lists. Do they have the same `len`? whats in them? Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: Of course performance is suffering, you're using an n^2 algorithm. Fix that instead of trying to run multiple threads.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think he's intentionally doing the product, not the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually do need to compare the cartesian product (every element in `list1` against every element in `list2`, as opposed to just comparing each element in `list1` with the corresponding element in `list2`), the easiest way is to just replace your outer loop with a `map` call to a [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) or a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).

The only trick is that you don't want to try to share that mutable `key` dict; instead, pass back the individual dicts and merge at the end.

For example:

```
def compare_to_list2(i):
    key = {}
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        matched = False
        try:
            matched = match_function(list[i]['typeforma'], list[i]['typeformb'],list[j]['typeforma'], list[j]['typeformb'], ) 
        except:
            print("Error",i,j)
        if matched:
            # store two matches in the dictionary
            key[list2[j]['id']]=list1[i]['identifier']
            break;
        j+=1
    return key

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor as x:
    key = {}
    for result in x.map(compare_to_list2, range(len(list1)), chunksize=1024):
        key.update(result)
```

Experiment with `chunksize`, but first, there are ways to improve on this. For just one example, you should really be iterating directly over `list1` and `list2`, not over `range(len(list1))` and `range(len(list2))`—and doing that won't just make things simpler, but also more efficient, especially with large chunksizes. In fact, it's often best to simplify first, and then optimize.